# Truecrypt file RevoveryProblem

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, passwords, truecrypt, hard-drive-recovery

I faced a terrible thing,that is when I use virus software to scan my computer(at the same time,I mount my external drive,but I didn't type truecrypt password to open the drive),there is no virus in my computer.Things happened.

When I tried to use password to open the drive,the password does not work.It's invalid.

Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of problem? And how to recover all important data in external drive?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the volume header?

Comment: I'm lost. What "Things happened"? I'm pretty sure an AV scan shouldn't mess with a closed TrueCrypt volume (never did for any of mine), so something else had to touch it for it to become corrupted. If you have a TrueCrypt Rescue Disk, or a backup of the volume header, you can use that to restore it. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a truecrypt rescue disk, you can boot it to restore the volume header to the MBR, or to permanently decrypt the drive contents.  You'll still need to know the correct password though.